# polling from nservicebus input queue

Tags: nservicebus

I just started writing pub/sub and the way that I doing this is that I will have a console app that runs every x hours and putting processed list as queue message (1 item per message).  Now, on the pub side, I want to listen the input queue and as soon as a message arrives, I would like to publish.

I know I need to set the input queue name and polling intervals in the config file, but how do I make so that the pub actually keeps polling from the input queue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this article about [scheduling recurring tasks in NSB](http://mookid.dk/oncode/archives/1507).  I think you can use this technique and eliminate the need for 2 separate processes.

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is to create a class that implements `IHandleMessages<YourMessageTypeHere>`, and in your initialization code, use

```
IBus bus = Configure.With()
                    ...
                    .UnicastBus()
                        .LoadMessageHandlers()
                    .CreateBus()
                    .Start();
```

`LoadMessageHandlers()` will scan the current assembly for `IHandleMessages` implementations. Whenever a message arrives, the handler will be invoked.

(Disclaimer: This works for NSB 2.1; I haven't used 2.5 yet.)